# Can i let user to select which screen they want to load when they open app next time?

Tags: flutter

Initially when the user log in and go settings page can we let user to select which screen they want to be the home screen next time when the use logs in.
Example:

1. Splash Screen > Checks user is logged in> if logged in Home screen else Log in Screen.
2. Let user select which screen they want to be landed next time when logs in or reopening the app let's say products screen.

Comment: you can use routes and  user selected root name save in SharedPreference

Comment: is it ideal to let the users select routes?

Comment: yes, if don't want this then first time initState store(change value) auto then user app open second time  user move on another route.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to specify the user login id in the splash screen when the app is open it will check user login or not if the user login you can route it to whatever you want otherwise you can redirect to the login screen. 
        
    I Used firebase for user authentication you can get an idea of how to save user id and get user id on splacescren using the shared preference plugin
        
        ///firebase login function
          static Future<User?> fireLogin({String ?email, String ?password,bool ?isManager,context}) async {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
            try {
              final loggedInUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email.toString(), password: password.toString());
              print(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
              sharedPreferences.setString("User UID",_auth.currentUser!.uid );
             var  userId = sharedPreferences.getString("User UID");
             sharedPreferences.setBool("isManager", isManager!);
             sharedPreferences.getBool("isManager");
             var isManagerValue = sharedPreferences.getBool("isManager");
              print("userId------"+isManagerValue.toString());
              if (loggedInUser != null) {
                isManager == false
                    ? Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context!,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => EmployeeBottomNavBar()))
                    : Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context!,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ManagerBottomNavBar()));
              }
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        
              if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                showToast(msg: "User not found!");
              } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password!') {
               showToast(msg: "Wrong password provided!");
        
              }
            }catch (e) {
              print(e);
              showToast(msg: "Please verify email and password!");
             /* final snackBar =
              SnackBar(
                  content: Text(e.toString()));
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);*/
            }
          }
    ///Placed these function into SplashScreen
        ///to check userID
         Future<dynamic>geFunction()async{
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= await  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            userId = sharedPreferences.getString("User UID");
            print("user id -----------"+userId.toString());
            sharedPreferences.getBool("isManager");
            isManagerValue = sharedPreferences.getBool("isManager");
            print("userId------"+isManagerValue.toString());
            navigatePage();
         }
        /// Place these method into your splash screen
         Future<void>navigatePage()async{
            if(userId ==null){
              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    context, RoutePath.selectUser, (route) => false);
              });
            }else{
              isManagerValue==true?Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    context, RoutePath.managerBottomNavBar, (route) => false);
              })
              : Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,RoutePath.employeeBottomNavBar, (route) => false);
              })
              ;
        
        
            }
        
         }
      Put getfunction into initstate in splash screen
         @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
             getFunction();
           
          }
```